# Storing user information within a static class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, silverlight

Let's say we want to keep user information after user logged in to application to share its data over multiple classes, what is the best way to do that.

Usually I keep things like this with a property in a static class :

```
public User CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

What's your idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of app?  WinForms?  ASP.NET?  WPF?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that, I edited the post.

Comment: @SaberAmani - So all of them? Are you looking for a consistent way to do it between the different technologies you've tagged?

Comment: @M.Babcock I afraid to say but yes. All of them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'user information'?  Preferences?  Or their identity, intended for authorizing actions later on?

Comment: @ChrisShain Let's say a simple object contains UserId and UserName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In WPF:** Imagine you have a class called `UserInfo` that contains all the information needed about the current logged-in user:

```
// You can use your Application.Current.Resources dictionary to store the
// current logged-in user info.
Application.Current.Resources["UserInfo"] = userInfo;
```

Then you can retrieve the current user info object anywhere in your application with the following code:

```
var userInfo = Application.Current.Resources["UserInfo"] as UserInfo;
```

Comment: Good point, but i *think* the question is more about whether you should use singletons rather than how to implement it. However, I agree, in WPF this is a good way to do it because it means you can bind to your UserInfo in XAML. +1

Comment: I usually avoid the use of Singleton classes because of testability problems, moreover, it it increases the complexity of your code. In my opinion the use of Application.Resources dictionary object is easier and simpler + it's testable :D

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing is to store the user information within a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This is a well-known pattern that is used quite commonly in desktop applications. There is also a lot of stigma related to the singleton pattern, it is often frowned upon, due to a few drawbacks:

- Testability, if you have a singleton that is not exposed via interface it is not possible (or easy) to test your code.
- Scalability, a singleton will always be a singleton so you cannot share this responsibility 
  between multiple instances to allows your application to scale up. This is typically only a concern in server-side application. On the desktop this really does not apply
- Concurrency, do you have multiple threads accessing your singleton? if so, you need to make it thread safe.

In your context within a desktop application the only one of the above that is likely to be an issue is the first, testability. In that case just define an `IUser` interface and you're good.

In summary, yes, this is fine. I have used this pattern myself many times in the past.